# Why is the pointer not free and doesn't it bring me same value of a variable?

Tags: c, pointers, free, dangling-pointer

In the below code I free the pointer `ptr` but still `*ptr` retuns me the same value. If I free the variable then it should give me some garbage value but it didn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int *ptr=&a;
    printf("%d, %d \n",a,*ptr);
    free(ptr);
    printf("%d, %d \n",a,*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) is not for "freeing" pointers. It is for de-allocating memory that has been allocated using [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)

Comment: *"it should give me some garbage value"* - how do you know that the value you receive *isn't* a "garbage value"?

Comment: @UnholySheep I declared varable a and assigned it a value of 5.
and pointer ptr gave the addreass of a. So value  recieved isn't different from a i.e.5.

Comment: `free` means you are returning the memory to the system and promising not to use it again. It does not say what the system will do with it. It certainly doesn't say the system has to put a "garbage" value in it. But you must not access freed memory. The result is Undefined Behaviour. UB means it can get a wrong value, it can crash, it can appear to "work" and any other unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Again, why do you think that 5 *isn't* a garbage value? There is no definition of a garbage value, so it might as well be the same value you read before

Comment: @Aziz
So,what's about this 
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int a=10;
    ptr=&a;
    printf(" %d \n",*ptr);
    free(ptr);
    printf(" %d \n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
It also returns me same value

Comment: @UnholySheep 
If it's garbage value then why I get same garbage value everytime whenever I run the program.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything. When your code invokes *undefined behavior* it might exhibit the same result every time. Or it might change depending on compiler versions/settings/some other random thing. Your code is broken and you can get any random combination of results

Comment: @VishalMourya: You’re still doing the same thing as your original snippet, you’re assigning `ptr` to point to `a`, not to the memory you allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can only `free` memory that has been allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` - you cannot use it to deallocate memory associated with an `auto` variable (the behavior is undefined):

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr );
*ptr = 5;
printf( "%d\n", *ptr );
free( ptr );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't allocated the memory yourself as John Bode answered, you cannot `free` it.

But even if you did allocate the memory, the `free` does not erase the contents of the memory block pointed by your pointer, it merely allows that block of memory to be used by something else, hence it "frees" it, not "erase"s. If nothing else happens to write to that memory block after you freed it, your content will still be sitting there.

Comment: No no no. Your answer was great until the last paragraph. But please do not recommend bogus practices that are no substitute for proper tools (such as ASan).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought that was "the" right practice, what's wrong with that?

Comment: It’s definitely not the right practice. Virtually nobody does that, because it doesn’t work: `int *x = malloc(*x); int *y = x; … free(x); x = NULL; *y;` opps, you assigned `NULL` to `x` but since `y` contained a copy of the pointer, accessing it is still not safe. No. The *real* way to save against such accesses is to use ASan or similar tools.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see, I am removing that part from the answer.

Comment: Even without the intermediate pointer, assigning `NULL` is not guaranteed to help. When `*x` is used, the C standard allows the compiler to assume `x` is not a null pointer, even if it was assigned `NULL` in the immediately preceding value. This means an optimizer that has cached `x` in a register can use the cached value instead of a null pointer, so `*x` could behave as if `x` still pointed to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

`free(ptr)` does not change the value of `ptr`. It merely asks the memory management software to release the reservation of the memory that `ptr` points to. Calling a function passes the **value** of its arguments; it does not pass any information about the identity of its arguments, so `free` does not receive any information about the `ptr` variable that would allow `free` to change that variable. It receives only a copy of its value.

Further, the behavior of `free` is defined only when it is passed an address that was previously returned by `malloc` or a related routine. It is not defined when given the address of a named object, such as `&a`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First:
the value `ptr` contains is not memory allocated with `malloc`.
For every `malloc`, there must be a `free`.
Since you are `free()`ing memory you don't allocate with `malloc`, you are invoking **Undefined Behaviour** (C and C++ programmers love this term)

Second: Since you are invoking **Undefined Behaviour**, the behaviour can be anything. A seemingly correct behavouring program can be in the territory of undefined behaviour.
You are simply lucky that you receive the same value over and over. On other systems your program could crash, kill an innocent grandma or simply push the delete button of the universe.